# Is a field declared inside an enum ThreadSafe?

Tags: java, enums, thread-safety

I have an enum declared as below in a class:

```
class Sample{
   private enum ObjectState{    

   VALUE1 {
      private boolean flag = false;

      @Override
      public final doSomething() {
         // update flag
      } 
   }

   VALUE2 {

      @Override
      public final doSomething() {
         // do Something
      } 
   }

   public abstract doSomething();

   }

}
```

Is the field flag defined in VALUE1 threadsafe?
If not then I'll make it volatile or change the datatype to AtomicBoolean.

Comment: Why would it be thread-safe?

Comment: You'd have to define *exactly* what you mean by "threadsafe" for that to be answered. There'll only be a single instance of the class generated for `VALUE1`, but that doesn't mean that all changes will be visible in all threads immediately, any more than it would for a regular object.

Comment: ARGH MUTABLE `enum`. This is really very awful. Never ever do this.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, I did see suggestions to use enums for implementing `Singleton` components, in which case they could be mutable and store global application state of some description. That really depends on what it's used for. "Never do" is not a good enough reason to not use a tool.

Comment: Take it as advice from someone with experience to someone with less @M.Prokhorov; the full story will not always be understood, you just have to take it on trust. I would not, under any circumstances, allow a mutable `enum` to pass code review.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, in my case, it would be because something which is called `State` has a state of its own, which means that two states which are supposed to be exactly equal can then change their meaning in some case. This just tells me that they are actually two (at least) distinct states, and should be implemented as such. This is not at all related to the use of `enum` keyword, that in itself is perfectly fine to me. They could be just `public static final` fields somewhere and would still get the same treatment from me.

Comment: @OP, object that extends from `Enum` in Java only gets special treatment when it comes to its instantiation, nothing else. This means that fields declared in `enum` instances have exactly the same meaning to them as fields declared in plain object classes. So, think: if you remove `enum` keyword, would the field be thread-safe or not?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov instantiation and serialization - although one can of course argue that the two are related. `enum` tries to guarantee that even if you serialize and deseraize and `enum` value there will stil be only a single instance.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, I do indeed clump together the instantiation which may or may not happen during deexternalization here. I also occasionally forget that serialization can skip normal instance creation.